# Counting number of words in a file using c++

Tags: c++

I have been asked to develop program to count no. of lines and words in the file, this is my trial, my teacher said that I cant use >> operator for counting words and comparing but I could not handle it.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int numberLines = 0;
    int numberWords = 0;

    void numberOfLines(){

    cout<<"number of lines is " << numberLines << endl;
    }
    void numberWords(){
    cout << "number of words is " << numberWords <<endl;
    }

    int main(){
    string line;
    char a = '';
    ifstream myfile("files.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open()){
    while(!myfile.eof()){
        getline(myfile,line);
        cout<< line << endl;
        numberLines++;
    }

    if ( a == ' '){
        NumberWords++;
    }

    }
    myfile.close();
    }
   numberOfLines();
   numberOfWords ();

   }
```

Comment: `while(!myfile.eof()){` -- [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Um... so why wouldn't removing `cout<< line << endl;` be a problem?

Comment: No, it wouldn't but I am asked to show up the lines too, so I used cout..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No `>>`, huh? I wonder how the instructor would respond to  `getline(myfile, word, ' ');`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a 3rd argument to `getline()`. This lets it pull data from the stream until it hits a character. Doing `getline(cin, line, ' ')`takes all the data until the next  and puts it into `line`. Your code might look like:

```
while(getline(inFile, line))
{
    ++numlines;
    stringstream lineStream(line);
    while(getline(lineStream, line, ' '))
    {
        ++numWords;
    }
}
```

The outer loop goes through the file and stores each line into `line`, then the inner goes through that line and counts each space. which correlates to a word.